# how to get all the status updates for Celery task?

Tags: celery, celery-task

I have the task, which contains the number of steps. As the task progresses, it should send the status updates to the result backend (Redis) like

```
Step 1 started
Step 1 completed
Step 2 started
Step 2 completed
...
```

with some extensive information about what was done within step. That is done with the use of [custom states](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states). The issue is that the status in the result backend is overwritten... And if, for example, the steps from 1 to 3 run very quickly, at least quicker than the polling period, there is risk to miss the information about steps 1 and 2.

So *how to make celery to keep all the status changes unless I read out all of them, not only the latest one?*

I'm not interested in getting all that info in real time, I'm only interested not to miss any status update information.

I looked into celery chains, to replace all the steps with separate tasks, but it seems not so easy to figure out what changed between two polling requests.
I also understand the status updates can be returned through RPC from worker, but was not able to find any example on how to report status that way.

Appreciate any ideas.
Thank you